# How can I upgrade from Tensorflow 2.0 alpha to beta given the exception: ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'

Tags: upgrade, tensorflow2.0

When trying to install the beta version of tensorflow 2.0 I am getting the following exception:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for wrapt
  Running setup.py clean for wrapt
Failed to build wrapt
Installing collected packages: tf-estimator-nightly, wrapt, tb-nightly, google-pasta, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: tf-estimator-nightly 1.14.0.dev2019030115
    Uninstalling tf-estimator-nightly-1.14.0.dev2019030115:
      Successfully uninstalled tf-estimator-nightly-1.14.0.dev2019030115
  Found existing installation: wrapt 1.10.11
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

What can I do about it?

---

**ERROR MESSAGE WHEN I TRY TO INSTALL WRAPT**

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install wrapt==1.10.0 --ignore-installed
Collecting wrapt==1.10.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/43/5453a18b5a06b0d714fd50f4634524c09af4bc41214f3dddf97f59090b23/wrapt-1.10.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: wrapt
  Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jdld9mo_\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jdld9mo_\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-mmlqban_' --python-tag cp36
       cwd: C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jdld9mo_\wrapt\
  Complete output (47 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
  copying src\arguments.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
  copying src\decorators.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
  copying src\importer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
  copying src\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
  copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jdld9mo_\wrapt\setup.py", line 79, in <module>
      run_setup(with_extensions=True)
    File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jdld9mo_\wrapt\setup.py", line 55, in run_setup
      setup(**setup_kwargs_tmp)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 202, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jdld9mo_\wrapt\setup.py", line 25, in run
      build_ext.run(self)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308, in run
      force=self.force)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
      return klass(None, dry_run, force)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 285, in __init__
      CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 129, in __init__
      if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
  TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for wrapt
  Running setup.py clean for wrapt
Failed to build wrapt
Installing collected packages: wrapt
  Running setup.py install for wrapt ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jdld9mo_\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jdld9mo_\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tbyepppf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jdld9mo_\wrapt\
    Complete output (49 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
    copying src\arguments.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
    copying src\decorators.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
    copying src\importer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
    copying src\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
    copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\wrapt
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jdld9mo_\wrapt\setup.py", line 79, in <module>
        run_setup(with_extensions=True)
      File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jdld9mo_\wrapt\setup.py", line 55, in run_setup
        setup(**setup_kwargs_tmp)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jdld9mo_\wrapt\setup.py", line 25, in run
        build_ext.run(self)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308, in run
        force=self.force)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
        return klass(None, dry_run, force)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 285, in __init__
        CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 129, in __init__
        if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
    TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jdld9mo_\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jdld9mo_\\wrapt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tbyepppf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Hi. Are you in a Python virtual, jupyter, conda, colab or whatever environment? What is the output of the following command? `pip list --verbose | grep wrapt`

Comment: Here is some advice that will be helpful. It is as much for readers considering helping as it is for you. (1) you are probably asking too many questions. Eight posts in two days means that you are not waiting for answers on one thing before jumping to the next thing. This would further indicate to me that you are not doing the necessary research. (2) You are adding chatty material about appreciating help, even though many editors have removed this from your prior posts. Technical writing is an expectation here. Meta references are available on request.

Comment: @AlexisBRENON:  wrapt                              1.10.11               c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages

Comment: This seems to be related to your compiler and libraries. `wrapt` use a C extension model and must compile it when you install. It seems that it doesn't find a library, `ld_version` being `None`. This issue has already be addressed as a [GH issue](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/issues/139#issuecomment-533039125) of the project.

Comment: @AlexisBRENON :  I installed the Visual Studio 2019 tools --vs_buildtools__1613254627.1513424936.exe-- and installed the 2019 version of Anaconda3.  I am still facing the same problem though.  Can you become more specific and guide me trhough the steps I must take?

Comment: I cannot help you that much as I am not aware of windows, visual studio and anaconda python packages management. However it does not seems to be a rare error. It appears because `wrapt` has been installed as a distutils package (by windows or VS or conda) and so `pip` refuses to remove it. You can try to remove it manually (delete `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\wrapt`) or try [other solutions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30191).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error but you can safely ignore this error.
You can read more about this, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2296#issuecomment-497883063) in this issue.

Or, you can first install/update the wrapt package using `pip install wrapt==1.11.0` or whatever version TF Alpha requires. Then just continue with TF Alpha installation.

Comment: I am getting the same error message when I try to install wrapt: ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.